# unexpected T_REQUIRE_ONCE that should be expected

Tags: php

```
<?php

/*
 * userprofile.php
 * bshades.com
 * Coded by Orgy
 * rrawbb[at]gmail[dot]com
 */

require_once("inc/_top.php");
```

That's my code that's having a problem.

Here's the error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_REQUIRE_ONCE in
>   /home/blacksha/public_html/userprofile.php on line 1

As you can see, the require_once isn't even on line 1, so I have no idea what the problem could be.

Comment: Try moving the require statement above the comment. Does it change anything?

Comment: is this file being included/required by something else or are you just loading userprofile.php directly from your browser?

Comment: Mind to show userprofile.php line 1? Nevermind, overlooked the comment.

Comment: If that's all you have, there could be some "funny" and invisible characters in the whitespace before require_once.

Comment: @Cyclone, yes, it works now (well I removed the comment block completely). What the hell?

Comment: To be honest, no idea. But sometimes it's just a stupid thing like comments that can mess with the rest of your code.

Comment: Try copy-paste the code from this question to replace what you have now.

Comment: it seems that it isn't recognizing the linebreaks in the code.

Answer (score 4):

`NBSP`. You had an invisible non-standard whitespace character before your require statement. That's the only reliable way to reproduce this error.

```
eval(    chr(0xA0) . ' require_once(1); ' );
      # that's nbsp

// PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_REQUIRE_ONCE in
```

`0xA0`/nbsp gets interpreted as bareword at that position. Basically the same as having a constant right in front of your statement:

```
ASCII require_once(123);
```

Answer (score 3):

This error code can also be reproduced if you forgot the trailing semi-colon ;  to terminate a statement...

i.e.

```
define('FOO', 'foo')
require_once('foo.php');
```